# MediaDevices.enumerateDevices() is not showing virtual webcam in browser but google meet and other website are showing

Tags: google-chrome, webrtc, mediadevices, google-meet, virtual-webcam

I use [Google meet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Meet) in [Chrome browser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome) for online video meeting. In Google meet I can select my webcam in video devices. I can select any real hardware or virtual webcam and thats works well.

I am sure Chrome detect all real or virtual webcam see content of `chrome://media-internals/`

[image]

But [`MediaDevices.enumerateDevices()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/enumerateDevices) is only showing real hardware webcam and not showing virtual webcams.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
    <script>
        (async () => {
            await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true, video: true });
            let devices = await navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices();
            console.log(devices);
        })();
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Hereis output of console in devtools:

```json
[
    {
        "deviceId": "",
        "kind": "audioinput",
        "label": "",
        "groupId": "a71e32bec65bc4788683c156cfbc3c005bce4535b980209e4a455973bd93f36a"
    },
    {
        "deviceId": "",
        "kind": "videoinput",
        "label": "",
        "groupId": "03e0a9c9e71757f81bef3f3a74c4a56785b2d3d103a7de883101e509c233977f"
    },
    {
        "deviceId": "",
        "kind": "audiooutput",
        "label": "",
        "groupId": "a71e32bec65bc4788683c156cfbc3c005bce4535b980209e4a455973bd93f36a"
    }
]
```

How come Google meet and other websites are showing all camera including virtual camera and why `MediaDevices.enumerateDevices()` is not showing virtual camera?

Comment: the lack of a label in the enumerateDevices output suggests you don't have getUserMedia permission for some reason. Are you trying on something like a file:/// url? Try on a page like https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/devices/input-output/ instead please.

Comment: Thanks @PhilippHancke, you are right I was running html via file:// so I was seeing limited details but via http:// I am able to see all devices. Please post this as answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An empty label and only the default devices being shown in `enumerateDevices` after successful `getUserMedia` is an edge case that can only happen when testing on `file:///` urls. It should work normally on `https://` urls (and on localhost) where a successful getUserMedia call grants permission to the extended list of devices (see this [PSA](https://groups.google.com/g/discuss-webrtc/c/qGdSM-Cs3bc/m/1V0iqPXVCwAJ?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer) for details)

Comment: Is there any workaround to to see extended list via `file:///` only?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68920496/mediadevices-enumeratedevices-is-not-showing-all-the-media-devices-when-access

Comment: the --allow-file-access-from-files used to work but may no longer.